# Does ArcGIS Online support ODBC?

Tags: arcgis-pro, arcgis-online, odbc

I'm trying to figure out if ArcGIS Online (as our database host) supports ODBC connections. My workflow is such that the data I maintain in ArcGIS Online needs to flow into Adobe Indesign for table populating. In order to do this, I have to use a 3rd party software which allows me to connect ODBC or CSV data sources to InDesign. We're a small company trying to automate anything where we can, and this would make a huge difference in our workflows. Does anyone has any information about what database ArcGIS Online uses, and whether they support ODBC.

Comment: Technically, AGOL uses every database that the resource providers use (which is quite a few), but direct ODBC access would violate security best practice, so this doesn't seem likely.

Comment: Gotcha- I hadn't thought of that. Sounds like what I'll need to do then is just keep updated spreadsheets (lots of scripting options there). Thanks for the insight @vince

Comment: I would agree with vince that I don't think this is going to be allowed for you to odbc directly into their source database.  That said, there definitely are lots of scripting options for import/export workflows.  Also, I don't know your situation or what is supported for your platform, but may look at webhooks https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/arcgis-online/sharing-collaboration/how-to-create-a-hosted-feature-service-webhook/ too. May be able to help either auto-update directly, or at least auto keep a spreadsheet up-to-date depending on how it's set up and your situation.